# CSS: Designing for the web, pg 182, word spacing and justify

Tags: html, css

> Justifying    a   line    with    text-align  set to  justify often   causes  the word    spacing to  stretch or  shrink. **Text  is  justified   starting    from    the
>   adjusted  word    spacing.**  A   browser may use any of  many    different   algorithms  to  justify text,   but the better  algorithms  ensure  that    the
>   **average space   in  the paragraph   is  close   to  the adjusted    word    spacing.**  You may want    to  adjust  the word    spacing to  improve the text's
>   appearance.

What does he mean by 'adjusted word spacing'? I thought that word-space was 'normal by default (specified by the font used), then you justify by increasing/decreasing from this mean value. He's indicating that, justification takes place from an **adjusted** value.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this [codepen](http://codepen.io/zakkain/pen/Dsvez) - it's from [this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-spacing/) article that explains it.

He basically utilizes `word-spacing` - sets it to normal and gives it a value.

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
  <div class="module"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
  word-spacing: 3em;
  padding: 1em 0 0;
}
.module {
  background: lightsteelblue;
  height: 5em;
  width: 5em;
  display: inline-block;
  /* reset word-spacing so that text inside this box is spaced normally */
  word-spacing: normal;
}
```

Looks like he is referring to the nuances between browsers. Each browser has a different 'normal'. It's one of the reasons some people use 'normalize' or resets. He's talking about changing the value to improve appearance, sometimes when you justify text, it looks horrible! Take a look at the link above.